# Problem running Test-SqlAvailabilityGroup in a Scheduled Task

Tags: sql-server, scheduled-tasks

I have a powershell script in which I am checking the Availability Group status of a 2 server cluster to determine the health of the cluster. Script runs fine on both servers when I run it manually, however I am trying to schedule the run with a scheduled task and have run into an issue. The scheduled task runs as expected on the primary node, however when running on the standby node, it returns an empty result instead of the Healthy status. No idea what might be causing this. I appreciate any help you can provide.

```
$svr = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $hostname;
$svr.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = 0; 

foreach ($availabilityGroup in $svr.AvailabilityGroups)
{
    $agName = $availabilityGroup.Name
    $primary = $availabilityGroup.PrimaryReplicaServerName

    $witnessFile = Get-ClusterResource -Name "File Share Witness" | Select-Object *
    Write-Output("AG Name: " + $agName)
    Write-Output("Primary Node: " + $primary)
}

#test availability group health
$agPath = "SQLSERVER:\SQL\$($Primary)\DEFAULT\AvailabilityGroups\$($agName)"
$agHealth = Test-SqlAvailabilityGroup -Path $agPath

$clusterNodes  = Get-ClusterNode 
$agStatus = "UNHEALTHY"
$clusterState = "HEALTHY"
$witnessFileStatus = "UNHEALTHY"

foreach ($node in $clusterNodes)
{
    if ($node.State -ne "Up") 
    {
        $clusterState = "UNHEALTHY"
    }
}

if ($agHealth.HealthState -eq "Healthy")
{
    $agStatus = "HEALTHY"
}

if ($witnessFile.State -eq "Online")
{
    $witnessFileStatus = "HEALTHY"
}

Write-Output("AG Status: " + $agStatus)
Write-Output("Cluster State: " + $clusterState)
Write-Output("Witness File Status: " + $witnessFileStatus)
```

I tried to run the task as an admin user, network service and system with no luck.